# Python поиск и замена числа в строке на измененное арифметически

Tags: python, строки, числа, re

Имеется строка необходима в ней заменить числа на 10% большие от исходных
Можно заменить все символы на определенные но как выполнить арифметику?

```py
a = "_u1_v12 10 яблоко 20 вес32вес23вес33и 78"

print (re.sub('\d', '4', a))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

> *repl* can be a string or a function

> If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) argument, and returns the replacement string

Отвечая на вопрос: "*как выполнить арифметику?*":

```py
import re


def increase_by_10_perc(m: re.Match) -> str:
    # Do whatever you want with re.Match obj and return a string
    d = int(m[0]) * 1.1
    return f'{d:.2f}'


a = "_u1_v12 10 яблоко 20 вес32вес23вес33и 78"

print(re.sub(r'\d+', increase_by_10_perc, a))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное все заработало.